# How to access a .dll from Nuget, using fsharpc, on Linux

Tags: .net, linux, f#, nuget

I am trying to use an external assembly from my fsharp code on Linux, and despite following the "-r:filename.dll" practice that I see others using, it's still failing for me.

First, the source code:

```
tlewis@dev-aug16:~/dev/fsharp$ cat sqlp.fs
open FSharp.Data.SqlProvider

printfn "hw, sp"
```

As you can see, I'm just opening the package, not doing anything with it.

Second, let's look at my nuget directory:

```
tlewis@dev-aug16:~/dev/fsharp$ find nuget/
nuget/
nuget/SQLProvider.1.0.36
nuget/SQLProvider.1.0.36/SQLProvider.1.0.36.nupkg
nuget/SQLProvider.1.0.36/lib
nuget/SQLProvider.1.0.36/lib/FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll
```

As you can see, I only have the one package installed.

Third, let's look at how I'm invoking fsharpc:

```
tlewis@dev-aug16:~/dev/fsharp$ fsharpc --warn:5 --nologo -g -r:/home/tlewis/dev/fsharp/nuget/SQLProvider.1.0.36/lib/FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll sqlp.fs --target:exe --fullpaths -o exe/sqlp.exe

/home/tlewis/dev/fsharp/sqlp.fs(1,18): error FS0039: The namespace 'SqlProvider' is not defined
```

I am using the absolute path to the dll file, along with "--fullpaths", as I have seen others doing.  Despite this, fsharpc is still not finding the namespace.

Finally, here's my fsharp version; it's just the standard version from apt on a modern ubuntu:

```
tlewis@dev-aug16:~/dev/fsharp$ dpkg -l fsharp
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                   Version          Architecture     Description
+++-======================-================-================-==================================================
ii  fsharp                 4.0.0.4+dfsg2-2  all              functional-first programming language - compiler f
```

I can compile simple programs fine.

Any help is appreciated; thanks!

Comment: I believe the namespace you need to open is `FSharp.Data.Sql` to use the Sqlprovider. Were you editing this in VSCode or Visual Studio you should be seeing some errors already.

Comment: @s952163, that was indeed my problem!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use the SqlProvider you need to:

`open FSharp.Data.Sql` and not `Fsharp.Data.Sqlprovider`.

See the [SqlProvider docs](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/general.html/).

It also helps if you can troubleshoot it in F# Interactive first.